# open office set .ods file as active sheet

Tags: java, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to set my saved `.ods` sheet as the active sheet using the following Java code. I have the object of `XSpreadSheetView` and with that I can get the active spread sheet but to `setActiveSheet(XSpreadSheet sheetName)`, I have no idea how to find the sheet name.

```
xcomponent = (XComponent) xDesktop.getCurrentComponent();
XModel xSpreadsheetModel = (XModel) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XModel.class, xcomponent);
XController xController = xSpreadsheetModel.getCurrentController();
XSpreadsheetView xSpreadsheetView = (XSpreadsheetView) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XSpreadsheetView.class, xController);
```

Comment: So you have an .ods file that is open, and is the active document?  And you have a particular sheet in mind that you want to become the active sheet in this already active document?  If you don't know the name of the sheet you want, what do you know about the sheet - its position, maybe?

Comment: i want to open the .ods file suppose my_file.ods in open office without loosing the currently opened sheet suppose sheet1 data

Comment: So you want the new workbook to open as a background window?  Or, you want the new workbook to open in hidden mode (so the macro can work with it, but the user can't see it)?

Comment: i want the add new sheet to the current opened window

Comment: More like this: Workbook1 is open and is the active OpenOffice document.  Open Workbook2 in hidden mode, copy its active sheet into Workbook1, close Workbook2, make the new sheet in Workbook1 the active sheet?